# How to Auto Scroll to the Top when Alert is displayed

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, redux

I have created Alerts using Redux actions and they are generated whenever a post is successfully submitted or an error is generated.
The problem is when the Alert is generated, it shows at the Top of the webpage, below the Navbar. So if the Alert is generated after clicking a button way below the top area, the Alert does not show because its displayed below the Navbar.

I want to make it so that whenever an Alert is displayed, it automatically scrolls up to the top of the webpage so the user can see it. Is it possible with simple css, bootstrap?

Comment: May be you'd like to use `z-index` for your alert div. I'm assuming `position: fixed` for the alert `div`. If not make it `relative`/`absolute`/`fixed` along with giving a z-index higher than the div which is overlapping this one.

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for should be

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

first 0 represents the width, second height; to the top means 0, 0

check here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp

Comment: How would I leverage it into React jsx?

Comment: you got to do it when you display the alert, so if your alert is a component then maybe you set it up on componentDidMount, but i think it might be better that you used a fixed/absolute position for your alert, without the hassle of scrolling to top